# SQL REPLACE with NULL unexpected result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to replace certain varchar to NULL. Straight forwardly I used

```
SELECT REPLACE('abc', '1', NULL)
```

i.e. for every input varchar if there is at least a '1' within I want the whole input becomes NULL (e.g. '123' is NULL, 'abc-1' is NULL, etc.)

Whats bugging me is even when there is no match (e.g. no need to replace), it still gives me NULL. For instance running the statement above gives you NULL.

Why? And any workaround?

Answer to be picked with the "why" component and a nice simple workaround.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [**`REPLACE`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx) documentation:

> Returns NULL if any one of the arguments is NULL.

Based from the above, this query will return `NULL` for all columns:

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE(NULL, 'abc', 'a'),
    REPLACE('abc', NULL, 'a'),
    REPLACE('abc', 'a', NULL)
```

---

If you want to return `NULL` for every input that contains the `'1'`, you use a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN 'abc' LIKE '%1%' THEN NULL
        ELSE 'abc'
    END
```

Comment: Ok thanks if it was implemented like that. Although it seems an amiss to me, gotta live with that. Using CASE as a workaround is fine as well. Thanks.